# Windows doesn't recognize external hard-drive after installing Ubuntu (on internal hard-drive)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have installed ubuntu on my internal hard-drive using windows ubuntu installer and everything worked perfectly. I am able to run both windows7 and ubuntu.

I also have an external hard-drive which I only keep for data. At first, I could access the data (mainly pictures and music) from both ubuntu and windows7. Now, when I open it in windows7, it's doesn't show anything. It shows indeed that it's half full but I see no folders or files. From ubuntu I can open it perfectly, no problems there.

My question is: how can I make windows see the data from my hard-drive again? I don't really care about ubuntu recognizing it. I only use ubuntu for my homework.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the **partition format**. Windows works better on **nfts** format. Check your external hard drive and I suggest you  try to formatting it again in nfts (it will erase all the data on it)

Comment: It was already ntfs format. I used it only on Windows until a week ago when I had to install ubuntu. I downloaded windows-ubuntu installer and installed it on another hard-drive.

It worked perfectly with both ubuntu and windows in the same time. However, yesterday, when I tried to access it from windows, i encountered this problem. Formatting is not a solution at this moment.

Comment: have you tried on another computer? it may be a **windows** problem...